# Debugging PYTHON code blocks in org mode babel

Tags: python, debugging, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Is it just me, or is it really sort of a pain to debug code that lives inside a `babel` block in an `org-mode` buffer?

Principal interesting question would be *Where can I see the output of `print`'s?*

How do you debug your `python` code when embedding in inside `org-mode`?

Comment: There were also `org-mode` and `org-babel`... Anyway, I added the `emacs` tag. Maybe we can clean these comments now?

Answer (score 1):

First, in your code block header, set :results output to see print statements.

Then, see http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/09/27/Improved-debugging-of-Python-code-blocks-in-org-mode/